# convert group of points to create an image vb.net

Tags: vb.net, image, picturebox, system.drawing

I have a group of points.
I know how to draw the polygon in the panel
but now I don't know how to make it an image.

tried googling it but I can't find the answer

how can I make it an image?
is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim points(5) As Point
points(0) = New Point(50, 10)
points(1) = New Point(90, 30)
points(2) = New Point(75, 70)
points(3) = New Point(25, 70)
points(4) = New Point(10, 30)
points(5) = New Point(50, 10)

Dim img As New Bitmap(100, 100)
Dim gfx As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(img)
gfx.DrawLines(Pens.Black, points)
Dim strFilename As String = "C:\Junk\Junk.png"
img.Save(strFilename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
gfx.Dispose()
img.Dispose()
Process.Start(strFilename)
```

Comment: anyways why is there a loop?

Comment: Oops! You're right the loop isn't necessary. I originally was going to draw each line separately. I'll edit it out

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the image to come from the Panel on which you've been drawing, then you can use DrawToBitmap:

```
Dim Bmp As New Bitmap(Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height)
Dim Clip As New Rectangle(New Point(0, 0), Panel1.Size)
Panel1.DrawToBitmap(Bmp, Clip)
```

Which you can then, for instance, set in another panel:

```
Panel2.BackgroundImage = Bmp
```

Or save:

```
Bmp.Save("MyPanel.bmp")
```